# Magento 2 - Circular sequence reference error

Tags: magento2

Trying to create a Magento 2 module that will load after another, it looks fine to me yet I'm getting a weird error:

> Circular sequence reference from 'MYNAME_MagePlazaSMTP' to 'MYNAME_MagePlazaSMTP'.

My Module looks like this:

File structure:

[image: File structure of module]

module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MYNAME_MagePlazaSMTP" setup_version="1.0.0">
            <sequence>
                <module name="MYNAME_MagePlazaSMTP"/>
            </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

I know I'm missing something but cannot see it...

Answer (score 4):

Ah, just me being an idiot, the module was trying to load after itself creating a loop. Now it makes sense:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MYNAME_MagePlazaSMTP" setup_version="1.0.0">
            <sequence>
                <module name="MagePlaza_Smtp"/>
            </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Just had to make it load after `MagePlaza_Smtp` rather than `MYNAME_MagePlazaSMTP` (itself).

I'll leave this up in case anyone else finds themselves running in circles like I did!